# Prove that $f$ is diagonalizable if and only if $\sum_{i=0}^n \lambda_{i} \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I'm a bit lost with this exercise.

Let $e_{1},...,e_{n}$ be a basis of the $E$ $\;K$-vector space and $f \in \operatorname{End}(E)$ such that $f(e_{1}) = ...=f(e_{n}) = \sum_{i=0}^n \lambda_{i}e_{i}$, where $k \in K$ (eigenvalue). Prove that $f$ is diagonalizable if and only if $\sum_{i=0}^n \lambda_{i} \neq 0$.

How is it done?

If $f(e_{1}) = \lambda_{1}e_{1}$,$\;\;\;f(e_{2}) = \lambda_{1}e_{1} + \lambda_{2}e_{2}$ and so on.., then $\lambda_{1}$ must be the same as $\lambda_{2}$, so $f(e_{2}) = \lambda(e_{1} + e_{2})$, right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you when you say you're lost, but please tell us what you've tried or thought of.  Even a sketch is a good start.

Comment: You have no $k$ in your formula $f(e_1)=\dots$.

Comment: I'm not sure I believe what we're supposed to prove. Suppose $\sum_{i=0}^n\lambda_i e_i=0$. Then we have that $f(e_1)=\ldots=f(e_n)=\sum_{i=0}^n\lambda_i e_i=0$. Then $f(x)=0$ for all $x$. Hence $f$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: You certainly have not typed what you think you typed. Please be very careful.

Comment: The statement is not true, it lacks the condition that at least one of the $\lambda_i$ is not $0$. If $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \ldots = \lambda_n = 0,$ then $f$ is diagonalizable even if $\sum\lambda_i=0.$

Comment: Hint: Show that the matrix which represents $f$ has rank $1.$ Then you know that $f$ has $0$ as an eigenvalue with (algebraic and geometric) multiplicity of at least $n-1.$ And there is another eigenvalue (guess which) that depends on the choice of the $\lambda_i.$ What do you get if this other eigenvalue is $0$? What do you get if it is not $0$?